# Definition of localized source in electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I'd like to know the exact definition in classical electrodynamics of a localized source, e.g. localized charge density $\rho(\mathbf{r},t)$ or localized current density $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t)$.  Do we merely require that $\rho(\mathbf{r},t) \rightarrow 0$ or $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$, or is there a requirement on the *speed* of the convergence?

I can't seem to find a precise definition in any standard textbook -- most just seem to say the densities must go to zero, but I'm not sure this is enough to make certain integrals converge.

Comment: It depends on the situation. Some theorems (like Helmholtz theorem) require the divergence and curl of the fields (hence the sources) to go to zero _faster than_ $1/r^2$. But in some other cases we assume the sources are completely _confined_ in some finite volume in order to prove formulas.

Comment: So, in electrodynamics, what does it mean for $\rho$ and $\mathbf{J}$ to be localized? Convergence faster than $1/r^2$?

Comment: Again, I don't think there's any _universal_ definition for it.  The two specific cases I can remember now as the meaning of the sources being _localized_, are the sources going to zero faster than $1/r^2$; and the sources falling to zero _abruptly_ .

Comment: OK, thanks.  When you say _faster_, do you mean _strictly faster_?